# How to retrieve response from multiple url using Jsonarray in android

Tags: android, android-volley

This is my first url

http://www.adayalangal.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=1

there are up to 8 pages there...
 `

```
JsonArrayRequest productReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));
                System.out.print(response);
                pDialog.hide();
                JSONObject obj;
                DataModel dataModel;
                JSONObject uniObject;
                //code for retreiving web content


                    }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
                //hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(productReq);`
```

When i run this i got only the content from first page only... i want to retrieve the contents untill the response from the url becomes null... how can i implement this

Comment: Keep increasing the parameter value of page for every next hit. like page=2,page=3 in the URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Separate method for api calling like this:

Define one variable which check If previous Response was null or not

```
boolean isPreviousResponseWasEmpty = false;

private void getData(String pageNumber){
String url = url + pageNumber ;
JsonArrayRequest productReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(response));
                System.out.print(response);
                pDialog.hide();
                parseData(response.toString());
                    }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
                //hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(productReq);`
}
```

And Create seperate method to parse your Server Response:

```
private void parseData(String serverResponse){
if (serverResponse!=null && !serverResponse.equals("")){
                JSONObject obj;
                DataModel dataModel;
                JSONObject uniObject;
                //code for retreiving web content

}else{
 if (!isPreviousResponseWasEmpty){
   isPreviousResponseWasEmpty = false;
   getData(incrementedPageNumber);
  }else{
     isPreviousResponseWasEmpty = true;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Make some small correction and got the answer.. (Y)

Comment: how can i add these pages only when the viewpager reaches some range??  @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position)
                    {
                        if(position==(response.length()-2))
                        {
                            Log.d(TAG,String.valueOf(position));
                            pageNum++;
                            getData(pageNum);
                        }
                    }
the above code replace the viewpager with page 1 when it reaches the condition